# Osmsharp and Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am a student and I actually doing researches on how to use the library Osmsharp with Monodevelop.

I use the following code for the test :
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

```
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // create a router from an osm file.
        Router router = Router.CreateFrom(new FileInfo("demo.osm"));

        // instantiate route end coordinates.
        GeoCoordinate location_from = new GeoCoordinate(51.26565,4.7777);
        GeoCoordinate location_to = new GeoCoordinate(51.2741,4.79795);

        // resolve the end points and link them to the road network.
        ResolvedPoint from = router.Resolve(location_from);
        ResolvedPoint to = router.Resolve(location_to);

        // calculate the route.
        OsmSharpRoute route = router.Calculate(from, to);

        // save the route as a GPX file.
        route.SaveAsGpx(new FileInfo("demo.gpx"));
    }
```

(This code is a code from a tutorial for the library Osmsharp)

My problem is when I build the project, I have this error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for >Android profile?
>
> File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'

After some research, I have added a reference to the file 'System.Drawing.dll' and 'OpenTK.dll'. I have also added the "using" at the beginning of the file but I have the same error as before and I don't understand why.

I would like to know if it's possible to use the Osmsharp library in a Mono for Android project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing OsmSharp requires System.Drawing.dll, which is not available in Mono for Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will search in another way